# Why is my array not storing values which i retrieve from my firebase data base?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

So i am declaring my users array at class level which is perfectly fine and stores whatever value i put in it except when i retrieve it from my firebase database .... I have been struggling with this and the only error i can seem to link to this is maybe.

**Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug**

My array keeps telling me it is empty for some weird reason....

How can i fix this problem ?

`var allUsers = [User]()`

```
func retrieveUsers() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.allUsers.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users {

            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid != FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
                    if let name = value["name"] as? String, let age = value["birthdate"] as? String {
                        let calculatedAge = self.calcAge(birthdate: age)

                        let userToShow = User(name: name,age: calculatedAge)
                        print(userToShow.Name)
                        self.allUsers.append(userToShow)

                    }

                    }
                }
            }
        })
    print(allUsers.count)
    ref.removeAllObservers()


}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously. Put the `print` line in the completion block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asynchronous data retrieval :-)  Do you see 'userToShow.Name' printed out?  You're printing the count before the data retrieval has finished - try putting it into the completion handler

Comment: I do remember it working when i printed it out in the completion handler however does this mean i have to call all my methods who rely on this array in the completion handler or do i have to create a method that notifies me when it is done retrieving all the data ? As when i called another method in my viewDIdLoad it also returned nil ... Thanks for your help !

Comment: You need to trigger all subsequent actions from the completion handler - you can call tableView.reloadData(), or call MyClass.doNextThing()

Comment: It worked out man !! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question , much appreciated !! :-)